# Python database creation - MySQL error

Tags: python, mysql, database, creation

I have been trying to create a database in python using the MySQL module. Here's the code:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='test', port='3306')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print "server version:",row[0]
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I had errors in initial steps relating to the host name, which I changed from localhost to the local IP and added a port keyword which seems to work with the quotes only. Apart from this, I am encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\server_version", line 4, in <module>
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='bhavin', port='3306')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 1):

`port` should be an integer, not a string:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', 
                       user='root', 
                       passwd='', 
                       db='test', 
                       port=3306)
```

Though, note that `3306` is a [default port](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) used if not provided explicitly:

> port
>
> TCP port of MySQL server. Default: standard port (3306).

Comment: that gives me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\server_version", line 4, in <module>
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='test', port=3306)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")

Comment: @user3451879 and this is a different problem.

Comment: its taking 10061 as default port

Comment: @user3451879 nope, `10061` is not a port here.

Comment: @user3451879 first of all, make sure your credentials are correct and MySQL server is up and running.

Comment: Verified. Server is up and running.

Comment: @user3451879 what about database credentials?

Comment: Okay, I figured the error. Sort of a stupid mistake while reading from a net tutorial. I was trying to connect to the database without creating it. Now I wrote the query to create the database and I am getting the same error. Please suggest. Also, is there any other way in which I can directly create the database in MySQL without having any query written. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Any way you are not creating a db table with that code, you are going to get an error, like "No such table exists" or something like that. Your should try: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(" // columns of your table with the type like integer or varchar